# Multiple inheritance in ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: design-patterns, asp.net-mvc

[image: Situation]

In one case BaseWizardController should implement background functionality of BaseController->BaseConsumerController, in other case it should implement only BaseController.

Any ideas how can I do that?

**Update.**
I don't mean 'multiple inheritance' in direct sense.
I need some pattern, something similar to Decorator, that can help me to combine functionality of 2 controllers in one (implement BaseWizardController + BaseConsumerController in one case and only BaseWizardController in other).

Comment: That's not really multiple inheritance though.

Comment: There's no way to do that in the way you describe it.